# I currently use SVN with Linux. How do I add files from my Windows Desktop?

Tags: windows, linux, svn, unix, file

You know, the regular "svn commit". "svn up."

When I did svn co, it was linked with SSH.

```
svn co +ssh or something.
```

How would I link this with Windows?  I'm using Windows and I'd like to put some code i this SVN. What tools do I use to get started? Can I checkout normally, with the Linux syntax?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you want an SVN client for windows? What is a "link with windows"?

Comment: Use cygwin and the svn client.  These directions include using svn and ssh via cygwin: http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/cygwin.html#Accessing+Subversion+Repositories+from+the+Cygwin+command+line

Answer (score 6):

For Win you REALLY wan't to use http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/. It's a GUI to SVN and facilitates things a lot.

**EDIT**
You also might find this tutorial helpful: http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to use a Subversion client on Windows, the best option is **[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)**.

If you want to have *your own Subversion repository*, then do the following.

Subversion involves two kinds of parties: the **server**, which has all the data necessary to construct the repository, and the **client**, which performs most of the user-initiated operations against the repository. You need to do a few things:

- Set up a Subversion *server*.
- Add or create the relevant repositories.
- Make sure the server is visible to all the *clients* that want to see it.

Then each client simply accesses the server the same way, e.g. `svn co http://mycomputer/svn/shared/trunk`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the normal syntax but it's probably easier to use [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) which gives you a nice explorer plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from Linux to Windows, you'll want to install cygwin.  Lots of tools you'll really miss on Windows are available from cygwin.

It's good to know that TortiseSVN is there, but it's just a svn gui.  It's unlikely that anyone coming from a Linux environment would be interested.  I used it briefly then got rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check out repositories by URL, you will need to set up Apache, including the DAV modules. Check here: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5902186.html

Comment: In particular, you will be able to check repositories in and out like John Feminella shows above.

Answer (score 0):

Another option over tortoisesvn, if you use linux and windows (like me) AND you use eclipse on both is to use the eclipseSVN.  This way usage on both OSes are the same.  You can get it by doing a Software Updates in Help of eclipse.